# visual studio code php xdebug not working

Tags: php, debugging, visual-studio-code, xampp, xdebug

I installed XAMPP.
I also installed PHP intelliSence and PHP debug in Visual Studio Code.
I set php_xdebug.dll in .../php/ext/.

Though I set some breakpoint on my php file, it doesn't work...

**Can you show me how to debug php in vs code?**

> launch.json

```
{
        "name": "Listen for XDebug",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "port": 9010,
        "pathMappings": {
                "${C:/xampp/tdocs}": "${workspaceRoot}"
            }
    }
```

> PHP.ini

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
xdebug.remote_port = 9010
xdebug.auto_trace = 1
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "C:\xampp\trace"
xdebug.idekey = "phpstorm"
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue.
I fixed the following.

- I had renamed xdebug file name from default to "php_xdebug.dll" but it doesn't work so I tried not to change the name.
- Xdebug works well then I access to localhost/***.php.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution. You could mark your reply as answer.